# Could you please someone explain 3-d array slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
import numpy as np 

A = np.array(
    [ [ [45, 12, 4], [45, 13, 5], [46, 12, 6] ],
      [ [46, 14, 4], [45, 14, 5], [46, 11, 5] ],
      [ [47, 13, 2], [48, 15, 5], [52, 15, 1] ] ])
print(A[1:3, 0:2])
```

Please explain this. I have been struggling to understand

Comment: Have you checked the NumPy documentation? What specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a 3D array this way, what you are acutally asking for is to cut a part of each nesting level of those arrays:

```
A[1:3, 0:2, 0:3]
# ↑↑↑
# Of the outer array (the outer []), take elements 1 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive).
# Mind that counting starts at 0, so this is the second and third line in your example

A[1:3, 0:2, 0:3]
#      ↑↑↑
#      Out of the second level array, take the elements 0 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive).
#      This is the first and the second group of three numbers each


A[1:3, 0:2, 0:3]
#           ↑↑↑
#           This you did not specify, but it is added automatically
#           Of the third level arrays, take element 0 (inclusive) to 3 (exclusive)
#           Those arrays only have 3 numbers each, so they are left untouched.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [483]: A = np.array( 
     ...:     [ [ [45, 12, 4], [45, 13, 5], [46, 12, 6] ], 
     ...:     [ [46, 14, 4], [45, 14, 5], [46, 11, 5] ], 
     ...:     [ [47, 13, 2], [48, 15, 5], [52, 15, 1] ] ])
```

The whole 3d array.  If you need to put names on the dimensions, I'd suggest 'plane', 'row' and 'column':

```
In [484]: A                                                                                          
Out[484]: 
array([[[45, 12,  4],
        [45, 13,  5],
        [46, 12,  6]],

       [[46, 14,  4],
        [45, 14,  5],
        [46, 11,  5]],

       [[47, 13,  2],
        [48, 15,  5],
        [52, 15,  1]]])
In [485]: A.shape                                                                                    
Out[485]: (3, 3, 3)
```

Taking a slice on the first dimension (the last 2 planes):

```
In [486]: A[1:3]                                                                                     
Out[486]: 
array([[[46, 14,  4],
        [45, 14,  5],
        [46, 11,  5]],

       [[47, 13,  2],
        [48, 15,  5],
        [52, 15,  1]]])
```

Taking 2 rows from each of those planes:

```
In [487]: A[1:3, 0:2]                                                                                
Out[487]: 
array([[[46, 14,  4],
        [45, 14,  5]],

       [[47, 13,  2],
        [48, 15,  5]]])
```

The last dimension, columns, is left whole, the equivalent of `A[1:3, 0:2, :]` (trailing slices are automatic).

3D slicing is just the same as 1d and 2d (and 4d etc).  There's nothing special or really different about 3d.